# The master puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Take any angle in a circle

1. Divide that respective angle in equal proportions up to infinity intervals . Then apply a pattern that I had given below .
2. The numbers you obtain after doing so should be equal
3. Pattern - let's take 120 as a angle 120=1+2+0=3(pattern)
4. Divide the number 3 in equal proportions .let us divide it by 2
5. 3÷2=1.5
6. 1.5 =1+5=6
7. Which isn't the same number (3≠6)
8. So find the number

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> 9.

Let’s take angle $360^\circ$.

1. Let’s take a angle say

   > $360=3+6+0=9$.
2. Divide the

   > 360 by 2 = 45 = $4+5 = 9$.
3. Continue the process

   > 45 divide it again by 2 = 22.5 = $2+2+5 = 9$.
4. Doing this infinity times we get the same result.